# Improving an IRC bot

Tags: java, object-oriented, classes

I've recently started working on a java project, and the main purpose of it is to get better at Java.
I've decided to make an IRC bot for twitch. But after some hours of progress I already see my Bot class growing. And that leads me to believe that I'm learning bad habits or I'm just doing it all wrong.

So I would love a moment of your time to review my project, especially the bot class.

I've already rewritten it once and I'm happy to do it again if it means improving.

```
package bot;

import chatlog.ChatLogger;
import chatlog.LogMessage;
import db.mysql.Db;
import history.ViewerHistory;
import main.Config;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.jibble.pircbot.IrcException;
import org.jibble.pircbot.PircBot;
import org.reflections.Reflections;
import text.Template;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.*;

public class Bot extends PircBot {
    public Timer timer;
    private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Bot.class);
    private boolean _connected = false;
    private boolean amIOp = false;
    private String _default_channel = "";
    private HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> opList;
    private String _cmd_prefix = "!";
    private ArrayList<String> seenViewers;
    private HashMap<String, Command> chatCommands;
    private HashMap<String, String> myCommands;
    private ChatLogger chatLog;
    private Config c;
    private ViewerHistory vh;


    public Bot(String nickname, String channel, String auth) throws SQLException {
        _default_channel = channel;
        c = Config.getInstance();
        opList = new HashMap<>();
        chatLog = ChatLogger.getLogger();
        timer = new Timer();
        seenViewers = new ArrayList<>();
        vh = ViewerHistory.getInstance();
        vh.setBot(this);
        setVerbose(true);
        this.setName(nickname);
        connectToIrc(channel, auth);
        if (isConnected()) {
            loadCommands();
            loadCustomCommands();
        }
        msg(Template.get("bot_startup"));
    }

    public void connectToIrc(String channel, String password) {
        try {

            this.connect(c.get("irc.host"), Integer.parseInt(c.get("irc.port")), password);
            this.joinChannel("#" + channel);
            addOp("#" + _default_channel, _default_channel);
        } catch (IOException | IrcException e) {
            log.fatal("Couldn't connect to irc, make sure the settings are correct!");
        }
    }

    public void schedule(TimerTask t, int seconds) {
        timer.schedule(t, seconds * 1000);
    }

    public void repeat(TimerTask t, int delay, int repeatDelay) {
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(t, delay * 1000, repeatDelay * 1000);
    }

    private void loadCommands() {
        chatCommands = new HashMap<>();
        Reflections reflections = new Reflections("bot.commands");
        Set<Class<? extends Command>> classes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Command.class);
        for (Class s : classes) {
            try {
                Command c = (Command) Class.forName(s.getName()).getConstructor(Bot.class).newInstance(this);
                if (!chatCommands.containsKey(_cmd_prefix + c.getCmd())) {
                    chatCommands.put(_cmd_prefix + c.getCmd(), c);
                }
            } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            log.info("Loaded the command: " + s.getName());
        }
    }

    private void loadCustomCommands() {
        myCommands = new HashMap<>();
        try (ResultSet r = Db.select("SELECT input, output FROM command WHERE channel = ? ",_default_channel)) {
            while (r.next()) {
                if (!chatCommands.containsKey(_cmd_prefix + r.getString("input")) && !myCommands.containsKey(_cmd_prefix + r.getString("input"))) {
                    myCommands.put(_cmd_prefix + r.getString("input"), r.getString("output"));
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void addCustomCommand(String input, String output) {
        log.info("adding the command "+ input);
        Db.query("DELETE FROM command WHERE input = ? AND channel = ?", input, _default_channel);
        Db.query("INSERT INTO command (channel,input,output) VALUES(?, ?, ?)", _default_channel, input, output);
        loadCustomCommands();
    }

    public void removeCustomCommand(String input) {
        log.info("Deleting the command: "+input);
        Db.query("DELETE FROM command WHERE input = ? AND channel = ?", input, _default_channel);
        loadCustomCommands();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMessage(String channel, String sender, String login, String hostname, String message) {
        super.onMessage(channel, sender, login, hostname, message);
        if (message.startsWith(_cmd_prefix) && message.length() > 1) {
            String[] input = message.split(" ");
            String args[] = new String[input.length - 1];
            for (int i = 1; i < input.length; i++) {
                args[i - 1] = input[i];
            }
            if (chatCommands.containsKey(input[0])) {
                msg(chatCommands.get(input[0]).execute(args, sender, isOp(sender)));
            } else if (myCommands.containsKey(input[0])) {
                msg(myCommands.get(input[0]));
            } else {
                msg(Template.get("unknown_command"));
            }
        }
        chatLog.log(new LogMessage(channel, sender, message));
    }

    private void addOp(String channel, String user) {
        if (user.equals(this.getName())) {
            msg(Template.get("bot_is_op"));
            amIOp = true;
        }
        if (!opList.containsKey(channel)) {
            opList.put(channel, new ArrayList<String>());
        }
        ArrayList<String> userList = opList.get(channel);
        if (!user.equals(this.getName())) {
            if (!userList.contains(user)) {
                userList.add(user);
                if (!user.equals(_default_channel))
                    msg(String.format(Template.get("found_op"), user));
            }
        }
    }

    private void removeOp(String channel, String user) {
        if (user.equals(this.getName())) {
            amIOp = false;
        }
        if (opList.containsKey(channel)) {
            if (opList.get(channel).contains(user)) {
                opList.get(channel).remove(user);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onUserMode(String targetNick, String sourceNick, String sourceLogin, String sourceHostname, String mode) {
        super.onUserMode(targetNick, sourceNick, sourceLogin, sourceHostname, mode);
        String[] u = mode.split(" ");
        if (u.length == 3) {
            if (u[1].equals("+o")) {
                addOp(u[0], u[2]);
            } else if (u[1].equals("-o")) {
                removeOp(u[0], u[2]);
            }
        }
    }

    public void msg(String text) {
        if (text.length() > 0) {
            this.sendMessage("#" + this._default_channel, text);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPrivateMessage(String sender, String login, String hostname, String message) {
        onMessage(_default_channel, sender, login, hostname, message);
    }

    public boolean isOp(String nickname) {
        return isOp("#" + _default_channel, nickname);
    }

    public boolean isOp(String channel, String nickname) {
        if (opList.containsKey(channel)) {
            return opList.get(channel).contains(nickname);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onJoin(String channel, String sender, String login, String hostname) {
        super.onJoin(channel, sender, login, hostname);
        vh.checkPlayer(sender);
        if (!sender.equals(this.getName())) {
            if (!seenViewers.contains(sender)) {
                seenViewers.add(sender);
            }
        }
        getUsers("");
    }

    public String[] getCommands() {
        String[] ret = new String[chatCommands.keySet().size()];
        int i = 0;
        for (String key : chatCommands.keySet()) {
            ret[i++] = key;
        }
        return ret;
    }

    public String[] getCustomCommands() {
        String[] ret = new String[myCommands.keySet().size()];
        int i = 0;
        for (String key : myCommands.keySet()) {
            ret[i++] = key;
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

You can find the project at [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/novaz/twitchbot/src)
And the bot class can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/novaz/twitchbot/src/2b70d4634a3f469bdd94f5df60a4ea94c11675f5/src/bot/Bot.java?at=master)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Classes**

Right now, your `Bot` class is responsible for the bot related functionality (connecting, sending/receiving messages), as well as managing commands.

I would create a class that manages all the command related functionality, you could call it `CommandManager`.

**Reflection**

*[if you have a good reason to use reflection, like allowing users to add new commands without recompiling, ignore the following]*

I wouldn't use reflection like this. The only advantage you gain is that you do not have to add a new line of code when you add a new `Command` class.

The disadvantage is that it is not very flexible (for example, you cannot easily ignore one subclass of `Command`), it is more complex and thus more error prone, users can add custom commands (only a downside if you don't want them to), it might be a security risk (this is speculation, but as the bot is exposed in the constructor, a user created command class probably could insert custom commands into the database or send messages), and it is slow (maybe not too much of a concern in this case, but still).

**Naming**

Most of the time, your naming is good and your code is very readable. But then all of a sudden, the reader is presented with variables like `u`, `c`, `vh`, or `ret`. I would change them to `userMode`, `config`, `viewerHistory`, and `commands` respectively.

Also, sometimes you use camelCase, and sometimes underscore. I'm sure that there is a reason, but I wasn't able to figure it out. For example, why is `_connected` using underscore while `amIOp` is using camelCase?

**Repeading Code**

Your `getCommands` and `getCustomCommands` methods look pretty much exactly the same. You could rewrite it like this:

```
public String[] getCommands() {
    return mapToArray(chatCommands);
}

public String[] getCustomCommands() {
    return mapToArray(myCommands);
}

public <K> String[] mapToArray(Map<String, K> map) {
    String[] ret = new String[map.keySet().size()];
    int i = 0;
    for (String key : map.keySet()) {
        ret[i++] = key;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

But the `mapToArray` method could also be simplified like this:

```
 map.keySet().toArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I do have a question though, what does the <K> do in the mapToArray method?

Comment: @Kaaz it's just representing a generic type (we need it because at compile time, we don't know if the map value is of type `Command` or `String`). You can read more about [generic methods in Java here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html) or [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html).